# React-native Android: Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ecmascript-6

I really don't know what's going on here.
I've set up a basic app and used a codesharing method found [here](https://differential.com/insights/sharing-code-between-android-and-ios-in-react-native/).
It's all very basic, so here's the code:

```
// index.android.js
// index.ios.js
import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import CompetitionAgent from './app/index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('CompetitionAgent', () => CompetitionAgent);
```

And the component:

```
//./app/index.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    View
} from 'react-native';

export default class CompetitionAgent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {nickname:''};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.information}>
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                        Welcome to the Competition Agent Connect app!
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                        When you are near a Competition Agent, you can join the session.
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{padding:10}}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.inputStyle} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    information: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
    inputStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#3E3134',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
    }
});
```

I know the error could be many things. So this basic layout produces the same error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    View
} from 'react-native';

export default class CompetitionAgent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {nickname:''};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.information}>
                    Welcome to the Competition Agent Connect app!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    information: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    }
});
```

The stacktrace:

```
E/unknown:React: Exception in native call
                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication
                                                  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                               Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208) 
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It ran just fine yesterday, restarting Android Studio didn't help either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're running your app from Android Studio, then you'll have to start the react-native packager from command line using `react-native start` from your react project's folder.

You'll also have to set up the Android port forwarding using `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.

Have you done those?

Comment: I'll give that a try. My mac was in standby since yesterday and everything was working fine... I'm not that familiar with Mac or the packager. Guess I've got a few things to figure out.

Comment: See if that works for you. The react packager occasionally dies on its own so it has to be started again.

Comment: Lesson learned and noted. Started packager and set up port forwarding and it's running again... Thanks

Comment: Great to hear that it worked. For what it's worth, if you start your app from the command line with `react-native run-android` (rather than from Android studio), then it should start the packager and do the port forwarding for you. But it has other problems that sometimes prevent it from starting...

Comment: does this happen with the release apk as well?

Comment: I get this error by running the app using the release apk. any hints?

Comment: @itdoesntwork how are you running your app? Do you see any error from the packager?

Answer (score 5):

It helped me when I have set up a correct Path for

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

and tools:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
```

Comment: That's useful information, but did you get the same error message? It seems strange because this error only appeared when I ran my application. Which means that the application has been build & bundled successfully in the past. Without the SDK and tools linked correctly, you couldn't have had a successful build, or am I wrong?

Comment: I had a "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message though also had "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication"
And when I have properly set up Path it has gone. BTW I had only a PATH for ANDROID_HOME but hadn't it for the tools.

Comment: In order to build you have to set up all paths like lvts described, do you have the packager running? The device has to to be able to connect to the packager in order to run the code you just built

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered the same problem when running a second React Native project in Genymotion emulator, I got the red screen with an error saying:

> Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication

However, in my case, it is not caused by the absence of those environment variables, as I added them in the very beginning. And the `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` command doesn't work for me either. I tried almost all the solutions I could find on the Internet, and none worked.

In my case, the solution is set the Debug Server host & port, as shown below:

Press `CTRL + M`, to open up the overlay of setting

[image]

Click 'Dev Settings', to go to the setting menu

[image]

Click on 'Debug Server host & port for device', and type in `localhost:8081` in the popup

[image]

And now you can just reload it, it should start working.

Hope this solution can help some people.

**Background:**

Actually, after setting up my development environment on Windows 7 Pro, when I ran my first React Native app, I got an error that says:

> Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure
>   your bundle is packaged correctly, or you are running a package
>   server.

To fix that problem, I set the Debug Server option to localhost:8081, and I expected that setting would take effect globally on the virtual device. But it seems to be working per application, which means I have to set it over and over again for new React Native projects.

I also setup the environment on a Windows 10 Home (following exactly the same procedure as I did on Windows 7 Pro), needless to set the debug server option, it does not give me such errors, and I can just run any React Native project without setting anything.

Comment: It should be noted that settings `localhost:8081` is for simulators and `<ip-address>:8081` is for devices via Wi-Fi ;)

Comment: That's probably why `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` didn't change anything for you because if you're running on a simulator there is nothing to reverse as a simulator already points to localhost

Comment: Yes, I am using Genymotion instead of a real Android device. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I would get this error when trying to get it to run on device. It was working fine on my simulators on my computer.

The problem was when I would do `adb devices` or `react-native run-android` I would get "ADB is Not Recognized as an internal or external command".

So my fix was to add the path to adb.exe's parent directory to my Environment Variables and then restart my command prompts. After I did that, `adb devices`  would not throw the "unrecognized internal external blah" and it listed my device. I then ran `react-native run-android` and on startup no more red screen showing the completely useless error message `Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication`! :)

So I found ADB was located in my folder:

```
C:\Users\Noitidart\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

I am on a Windows 10 system. Noitidart is my user name of the computer.

So I went to System Environemnt Variables then found "Path" then clicked "Edit", then clicked "New" and added in "C:\Users\Mercurius\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools".  Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. However, my paths were setup correctly, otherwise I couldn't have deployed to my device from the start :)

Comment: Thanks so much @DerpyNerd for your kind comment and kind +1 :)